# Email Validator Problems- Putting it all together

Tags: php, validation, email

I'm very new to PHP coding.
I've done tons of research to try and help me. As you can imagine I've gotten *tons* of material for help. The problem is when I'm trying to put it all together.

Specifically here is my problem. I've come across:

```php
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "e-Mail is Valid";
} else {
    echo "Invalid e-Mail";
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement it. As it stands now the validator checks the fields before the user has time to imput them..... I'm desperate

I'm sure the solution is really simple, but I've spent hours on this and am really desperate for this problem to be solved already.

Here's a link to the [page](http://joshbrown-designs.com/awalshphotography.com/email.php)

Here is the code for the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'> 
<title>AWalsh Photography - Contact Me</title>
<link href="style/main_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="email_container">
      <h1 class="email_head"> Contact Andrew walsh Photography</h1>
      <form id="email_form" name="email_form" method="post">
      <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname_input" id="fname_input" /><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname_input" id="lname_input" /><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="email_input">Your Email:</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email_input" id="email_input" /><br>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>



    <td><label for="email_conf">Re-enter Email:</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email_conf" id="email_conf" /><br>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>
    <label for="message_input">Message </label>
    </td><td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="45" id="message_input" name="message_input"></textarea>
    </td></tr><tr><td></td>
    <td>
    <input id="submit"type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>        
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>

<?php 

if($_POST['email_imput'] == $_POST['email_conf']){
    //stuff to do on success
    echo '<h1>Success!!</h1>';
} else {
    //stuff to do on failure
    echo '<h1>Sorry, The emails you entered do not match</h1>';
}


    $email_imput = $_POST['email_imput'];

if (filter_var($email_imput, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo $email_imput . ' is a valid email address.';
} else {
    echo $email_imput . ' is not a valid email address.';
}

$message_imput = $_POST['message_imput'];

$msg = "Email address: $email_imput \n" . "Message: $message_imput";

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com ';

$subject = 'AWP_email';



if (filter_var($email_imput)){

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $email);
}
if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $email)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent! Thanks for submitting your message. We will reply to you as soon as possible</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<h1>Sorry, There was an error in your imput. Please try again.</h1>");
  }

?>  
<span class="error"><?=$error;?></span>
<form method="post" action="">
    <h1> There was an error with your post</h1>
</form>     

</div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any input would be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden field into the form and check it's value when it's time to send the email.

```php
if (isset($_POST["some_hidden_field"])) {
    // put form validation and sending email here
}
else {
    // print the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether the page has been submitted or not. You might want to try `if ($_SERVER['METHOD'] == 'POST')` before making any validations